# Pandas How to retrieve the value of datetime index with apply lambda?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the Demo:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df_test2 = pd.DataFrame({'dt_str': {0: '03/01/2017-09:16:00',
  1: '03/01/2017-09:17:00',
  2: '03/01/2017-09:18:00',
  3: '03/01/2017-09:19:00',
  4: '03/01/2017-09:20:00'},
 'Open': {0: 21920, 1: 21945, 2: 21940, 3: 21981, 4: 21988},
 'Close': {0: 21945, 1: 21940, 2: 21981, 3: 21988, 4: 21977},
 'Volume': {0: 935, 1: 541, 2: 651, 3: 314, 4: 318}})

df_test2['dt'] = df_test2['dt_str'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M:%S'))

df_test2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df_test2.set_index('dt', inplace=True)


# The question is how can I get the value of the datetime index in lambda function

def condition(x):
    # handling index value, like checking the datetime's weekday
    print(x['dt'].weekday())
    return True


df_test2.apply(lambda x: condition(x), axis=1)
```

When I'm calling `x['dt']` it raised Key error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

xxx
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'dt'
```

### Update

if I use `x.index`, it raised:

```
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'weekday'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely enough, you need to use `x.name` instead of `x['dt']`, since `dt` is now the index:

```
def condition(x):
    # handling index value, like checking the datetime's weekday
    print(x.name.weekday())
    return True

df_test2.apply(lambda x: condition(x), axis=1)
```

(Also, note that when your function takes one param, it's redundant to use `.apply(lambda x: condition(x), axis=1)` - instead just write `.apply(condition, axis=1)`)

Output:

```
In [289]: def condition(x):
     ...:     # handling index value, like checking the datetime's weekday
     ...:     print(x.name.weekday())
     ...:     return True
     ...: 
     ...: df_test2.apply(lambda x: condition(x), axis=1)
1
1
1
1
1
Out[289]: 
dt
2017-01-03 09:16:00    True
2017-01-03 09:17:00    True
2017-01-03 09:18:00    True
2017-01-03 09:19:00    True
2017-01-03 09:20:00    True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: it also failed, the x.index is not the datetime object, please see the update.

Comment: Check now, @Dennis.

Comment: it works, thanks alot. BTW, why should it use x.name, not the x.index?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea, @Dennis. `x.index` is used for the columns of the row, since Series's don't have columns...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might stepped upon this question but is not sure why the accepted answer works (I would prefer to post it as a comment below the answer of DennisLi but I can't due to reputation):

I had a similar issue where I wanted to create a new column with values based on the hour of the datetime index.

What I realized when I did some trial and error with the accepted answer is that when we use `df.apply(lambda x: condition(x), axis=1)` then a row of the df is passed as x in lambda, in the form of a pandas Series with index the column names (as the documentation also refers) and column name the datetime index, i.e. 2017-01-03 09:16:00 . So this series, with this datetime as name, has of course an attribute 'hour' like in my case, or weekdays() callable etc.